# Prefix text blocks in bash

Tags: bash, block, edit

How can I add a specific prefix to a text block? Example:

I have a file like the following:

```
mo18jan2016
1100,1130,10279325
1400,1515,10309421
---
tu19jan2016
1130,1215,10312440
1245,1430,10312230
---
we20jan2016
0800,0845,10312220
1000,1100,10313524
```

and what I want to do is:

"for x in in "mo tu we th fr sa su" DO look for $x in the file and when you found $x, prefix "$x," to all following lines that start with [012] until the next line starts with --"

So the above becomes:

```
mo18jan2016  
mo,1100,1130,10279325  
mo,1400,1515,10309421  
---  
tu19jan2016  
tu,1130,1215,10312440  
tu,1245,1430,10312230  
---  
we20jan2016  
we,0800,0845,10312220  
we,1000,1100,10313524
```

The hard part here is to "look" for the variable, then do things as "below until you find a line matching the ^-- pattern".

Comment: what do you mean with prefix all following lines starting with [012]? Until you hi the next x (which means until the end of the block)?

Comment: Ok, longer: do a loop "x" for the elements: mo tu we th fr sa su. for each do: look for the line starting with $x. below that prefix all following lines with $x until the next line starts with "--" (actually "---" is in the above example, but that includes -- of course), then go on with the next loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Simple with Awk.

```
awk '# Set Output Field Separator to comma
  BEGIN { OFS="," }
  ! prefix { prefix=substr($0, 1, 2); print; next }
  /^---/ { prefix=""; print; next }
  { print prefix, $0 }' file
```

The overall logic is to capture a prefix if we currently don't have a prefix.  Seeing the separator line removes the current prefix.  If we do have one, print it in front of the current line.  Then we fall through to the next input line and start over from the beginning of the script.

Output will be to standard output; use the shell's redirection facility to save it somewhere if that's what you want.